# Django URL regex matches correctly with GET but not POST

Tags: python, regex, django, http

I'm working on a webapp that let's you poll a Django backend for IRC logs on a given date. My URL structure is:

`example.tld/weblogs/<example channel>/dl/<example date>.<example format>`

Users are able to GET query the following url scheme:

`example.tld/weblogs/<example channel>/`

to get a the last 100 lines of IRC data as well.

My URL matching file correctly routes to the proper view (`views.download`) when the request is an explicit GET, however I am unable to do a POST on just `example.tld/weblogs/<example channel>/dl/` and have the POST'ed form data sent to the same view as the explicit GET will.

For example, if a user types the explicit URL `example.tld/weblogs/foo/dl/2015-01-01.json` the request will be properly routed to the right view.
However, if a form submits a POST to `example.tld/weblogs/foo/dl/`, the POST request is sent to the view that handles requests to just `example.tld/weblogs/foo` (in this case).

project `urls.py`:

```py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from log import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^weblog/', include('log.urls')),
]
```

`log.urls`:

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.weblogs, name='weblogs'),
    url(r'^(?P<channel>[^, ]{1,200})/$', views.channel, name="channel"),
    url(r'^(?P<channel>[^, ]{1,200})/dl/(?P<date>[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).(?P<format>(html|json|yaml|xml))', views.download),
]
```

The GET requests look like this:

`"GET /weblog/example/dl/2015-08-20.yaml/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4621`

The POST requests look like this:

`"POST /weblog/example/dl/ HTTP/1.1" 200 74`

Comment: Regex patterns work as expected, the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex,  `[^, ]` is matching any character except commas and spaces, including forward slashes.

To exclude forward slashes, change it to `[^,/ ]`. Alternatively, something like `[-\w] +` might be appropriate.